# Bootmenu hiding it?

Tags: grub2

Is there a way to hide the boot menu ?
For example i got 2 ways of booting ubuntu/windows.
I want to hide boot and to boot directly to windows.
And also it may be reactivated for pressing two keys ?
Maybe sounds weird, but sorry. And hope it is not yet an question like this.

Comment: You mean auto-boot to Windows every time, and only show the menu when pressing a key like shift?

Comment: Yes ... that it is what i have said.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to edit your GRUB boot menu to not wait for your choice, and just boot either a default entry, or the last entry booted.

See [Ubuntu's Grub 2 Setup Community Help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup) for more info, some clips are below.

> GRUB 2 builds its menu (`grub.cfg`) by running scripts found in the `/etc/grub.d/folder` and the settings in the `/etc/default/grub` file. This file is recreated automatically whenever the update-grub command is run.

You could edit  `/etc/default/grub` and then run `update-grub`. These are probably some options you want:

### **GRUB_DEFAULT=**

Sets the default menu entry. Entries may be numeric, a complete menuentry quotation, or "saved"

1. **`GRUB_DEFAULT=0`** Sets the default menu entry by menu position number. The first "menuentry" in grub.cfg is 0, the second is 1, etc.
2. **`GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`** The information in this section applies to GRUB 1.98 and later. The "saved" entry enables the "`grub-reboot`" and "`grub-set-default`" commands to set the default OS for future boots.

   - **`grub-set-default`** Run from a terminal, sets the default boot entry until changed.

     1. The format is sudo grub-set-default X, with X being the menu entry position (starting with 0 as the first entry) or the exact menu string.

        Example: `sudo grub-set-default 3`
         Example: `sudo grub-set-default "Ubuntu, Linux 2.6.32-15-generic"`
     2. To obtain the existing menu entry choice number (starting from 0) or the menu entry "string", run:

        ```
        grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg
        ```

### **GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true**

If set to true this setting will automatically set the last selected OS from the menu as the default OS on the next boot.

- No commands need be run to set the default OS.
- Any time a menu entry is manually selected from the GRUB 2 menu, it becomes the default OS.
- This option currently does not work if your /boot directory resides on an LVM partition or RAID.
- For this to work **you must also set `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`**.

### **GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=**

Wait this many seconds for the user to press a key. During this period no menu is shown unless the user presses a key. If no key is pressed, control is passed to GRUB _TIMEOUT when the GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT expires. See the note regarding bugs to this feature at the end of this section.

The developers envisioned using this setting with a GRUB_TIMEOUT value of 0. This would give users a period of time (GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT) to display the menu by pressing a key, after which the system would boot without the menu being displayed (GRUB_TIMEOUT=0).

1. **`GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`**   No menu is displayed. The system is immediately booted to the default OS.

   - If the value is set to 0, and **if the SHIFT key is depressed during the boot process, the menu will be displayed.** This gives the user a method of interrupting an automatic boot which would normally not display the menu.
2. **`GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=X`**  X is a positive integer (e.g. 1, 5, 10, etc)

   The boot process will pause and display a blank screen or the designated splash image for X seconds. At the end of the time period, the system will boot. No menu will be displayed.
   While GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is active, the menu can be displayed by pressing any key.
3. **`GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=`**   No value entered after the `=` sign. 
   The menu will be displayed for the number of seconds designated by GRUB_TIMEOUT.

### **GRUB_TIMEOUT=**

Sets the time period in seconds (1, 5, etc) for the menu to be displayed before automatically booting unless the user intervenes.

- This instruction begins at the expiration of GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT.
- Setting this value to -1 will cause the menu to display until the user makes a selection.

---

So, probably adding/changing these lines in `/etc/default/grub` (changing the `0` in `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to whatever your choice is):

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

Then run `sudo update-grub`